# How do I detect average download speed?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

So I want to make an Speedtest alike, I am downloading an 100MB file (is it too much to test average download speed?).
I am getting an huge number and I can't calculate the average download speed like that...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Downloading Then Exit Sub
    Downloading = True

    Dim wc As New WebClient
    AddHandler wc.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf wc_ProgressChanged
    AddHandler wc.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf wc_DownloadDone

    wc.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("http://speedtest.ftp.otenet.gr/files/test100Mb.db"), tmp, Stopwatch.StartNew)
End Sub

Private Sub wc_DownloadDone(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs)
    Downloading = False
End Sub

Private Sub wc_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs)
    Me.Label2.Text = (e.BytesReceived / (DirectCast(e.UserState, Stopwatch).ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0#)).ToString("#")
End Sub
```

Offtopic: Is there also a way to calculate the average upload speed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The huge number you are getting is bytes/second. You need to divide it by `1024` to get Kilobytes/second or `(1024 * 1024)` to get Megabytes/second

```
Me.Label2.Text = (e.BytesReceived / (DirectCast(e.UserState, Stopwatch).ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0#) / (1024 * 1024)).ToString("#")
```

To get Megabits per second like speed test does you need to also multiply by 8

```
Me.Label2.Text = (e.BytesReceived / (DirectCast(e.UserState, Stopwatch).ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0#) / (1024 * 1024) * 8).ToString("#")
```

Comment: My code only show what's being downloaded, when it reaches 100mb it stops at value 100. I want to get the average speed but I am only getting the mb I am downloading...

Comment: Then something is wrong with your `(DirectCast(e.UserState, Stopwatch).ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0#)` because the only way to get 100 when done is if that equaled `1`

Comment: I deleted DirectCast and I am only using Me.Label2.Text = (e.BytesReceived / 1024 ^ 2) now.

Comment: It stops at number 8 buddy...
How can I make it to calculate the average?

Comment: Then you are getting 8 Megabytes /second average The result you get ***is*** the average.

Comment: Impossible... http://www.speedtest.net/my-result/5661633403
That's my speedtest using speedtest.net

Comment: Do the math yourself and check. in `wc_DownloadDone` do (DirectCast(e.UserState, Stopwatch).ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0#).ToString("#")` and `new FileInfo(tmp).Length.ToString("#")` and put them in text boxes. Devide those two numbers in a caculator to get the "total size of file / total time of file" that will give you the average bytes/second for the file. Then devide by 1024 twice in the caluclator. That will be the average time. See if you get 8. It is very possible that the speed test is giving you Megabit/sec which means you need to multiply the result by 8.

Comment: So I have to multiply my final result by 8?
Can you give me a little snippet on how to do that buddy?

Comment: I just checked, Speedtest.net gives you your answer in Megabits/second not megabytes per second. you definatly need to multiply by 8. Throw a `* 8` inside the parenthesis on it before you do the `.ToString()` to do it.

Comment: I think it works great now (1024 * 1024) * 8).ToString("#") & "MB"
But it still doesn't getting me my real speed, it says 83 mb/s...

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how accurate you want the speedtest to be, the larger the file the more accurate it is. But this can be a big annoyance/data hog for the user.

The big number appears because it's in bytes, to get Mb/s you need to do `Your result / 1024^2`.

Comment: My code only show what's being downloaded, when it reaches 100mb it stops at value 100.
I want to get the average speed but I am only getting the mb I am downloading...